# How to use photoshop graphic files (*.psd?) in xcode?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, photoshop

I heard that I can directly import photoshop psd file into a XCode project to use the images provided by the psd file. However, i could not find a way to import the psd file into the interface builder. Can some expert help me out here? How do i make use of a psd file? Or what is the another file format i need to use? thanks!

Comment: You can't automatically slice and export from Photoshop without scripting due to overlapping, and you can't use the PSD in inteface builder. You have to select, copy merged, new file, paste, press file > save for web..., and choose png.